# How to work with date.time using Data.table

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

when you use the fread function to ingest data to R using data.table library, the dates are always read as yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss, like for example:
`2018-11-21T20:31:57`

I want to use this like a date, but in the fastest way possible. Till today, I always use lubridate´s function ymd_hms() to convert to date, but I came here to ask if it is possible to do using only data.table

I have make trials using IDate, IDateTime, as.IDate, .. but nothing of this is working for me.

Code example:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(date = "2018-11-21T23:32:54")
IDateTime(data$date)
as.IDate(data$date)
as.Date.IDate(data$date)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have edit the question with the date in correct way

Answer (score 4):

You are using `date = "2018-20-21T23:32:54"` and I don't know any calendars that have either 20 or 21 months.

Comment: Hmm, wondering if there is a date.time class for other planets in R

Comment: You are ritght, funny mistake from my part, I reedit the question with a well formated date...